# Ubuntu 13.10 running very slow unlike former win xp professional

Tags: 13.10, graphics, acer

I have always been a win xp user. I changed to ubuntu one 13.10 yesterday. I thought ubuntu might be much faster. It is so very very slow. What can b the problem? I used an USB to install ubuntu on my laptop (32 bit). This actually worked out good. Maybe my laptop is too old? It is an acer aspire 5610. I used win xp professional on it which was okay.

Now the new graphical designs move around super slow. Like the windows take long to open, everything is in slow motion. Even when I drag and drop items from external flesh drives on my desktop- sometimes they don't even want to be moved at all.  Or when I install new software it takes years for the icons to move into the right position on the launchpad. Even online videos do take too long, the voice is fine but the videos too slow.

Laptop information: acer aspire 5610
driver/graphic: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.3, 128 bits)
processor: Genuine Intel® CPU T2050 @ 1.60GHz × 2 
32 bit

Is this laptop to slow?

Comment: There's a post in [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2182103) that suggests running `sudo pam-auth-update --force` and rebooting.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the hardware of your laptop is too old for ubuntu 13.10. I'm not absolutely sure beacause an important information for judging this is the size of the RAM, which you don't tell. But at least the CPU is not strong. Note that Ubuntu needs more performance than Win XP.

If RAM is even lower than 1 GB, it is better to take another *buntu. Even with 1 GB your system will be slow with Ubuntu. Best will be Lubuntu. This variant is made for old hardware like your. The variant is not "weaker" than Ubuntu, but it fits to older CPUs and lower RAM size. There is e. g. no 3D-graphics in the desktop integrated. Lubuntu is much more like Win XP concerning the performance of the system. As a last remark: It's not true that Linux generally has lower hardware needs than Windows. It depends on the variant of Linux.